# MinionPro opticals lining figures

Tags: fonts, minionpro

I get warnings of the kind

```
pdfTeX warning: /usr/bin/pdflatex (file /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/type1/adob
e/MinionPro/MinionPro-Capt.pfb): glyph `eight.fitted' undefined
```

for all numerals and the viewer displays empty boxes only.

The problem disappears if I remove the `lf` option. Then I get the old style figures. Also normalsize lining figures work ok. Of course with `noopticals` as option the problem disappears.

Is that problem known?

Comment: You might want to try the recent `lcdf-typetools` version 2.99. A bug has been fixed, which created a bad `three.fitted` glyph.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that your question is related to the [MinonPro package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro). This package comes withs several versions of the .enc files that correspond to several versions of the OTF fonts (versions are 1.000, 1.001 and 2.000). The .fitted named digits are present only in the 2.000 version.

I suspect you have mixed the versions of the otf fonts (say MinionPro-Regular.otf in 2.000 version and MinionPro-Capt.otf in 1.00x version).
You should check the version numbers of yours fonts. For instance cd in a directory containing the fonts and :

$ otfinfo -v MinonPro-Capt.otf

HTH

Comment: just a reminder those Minion Pro scripts are out of date. The most up-to-date version (forked from the scripts on CTAN) can be found at [github.com/sebschub/FontPro/](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/).

Comment: Thank you. I have the correct .enc files (001.001). But if the .fitted named digits are only in version 2.000 then the problem must be with the encoding.

Comment: Hmmm ! There are no .fitted named digits in the 1.001 enc files (base-MinionPro-aa.enc) that I just download from CTAN.

Comment: @nnunes -- it would be a great favor to tex users if the scripts at ctan could be kept up to date.